# How to merge my dataframe to compensate for missing data without adding new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to manipulate excel sheet data to automate a process on excel(not a developer), i do have 2 dataframes:

one looking like the below(only difference is more columns)

```
Date                           Val1    Val2
    0   2020-09-29 13:22:57       5.34      3.2
    1   2020-09-29 13:23:12        4.5       Nan
    2   2020-09-29 13:23:44        Nan      56.4
    3   2020-09-29 13:24:01        24        0.3
```

as we notice for the one above the index are in order, and all the fields have dates populated but do not necessarily have all the other columns populated.

the second dataframe have the following characteristics, equal or more rows without any additional dates, also no duplicate dates but the additional rows are empty ones(NaT for Date and Nan for all other columns), the index of df2 are also not in order due to other processes:

```
 Date                          Val1    Val2
0   2020-09-29 13:22:57         Nan      Nan
5   Nat                         Nan      Nan
1   2020-09-29 13:23:12         4.5       Nan
4    NaT                       Nan       Nan
6    Nat                       Nan       Nan
2   2020-09-29 13:23:44        Nan       Nan
3   2020-09-29 13:24:01        24        0.3
```

what i basically need is to check for the matching dates, and if a date in df2 matching a date in df1 to populate the same exact value for the entire row of that date in df2 as in df without changing the location of the empty rows in df2 or adding columns:

expected output:

```
 Date                             Val1         Val2
    0   2020-09-29 13:22:57       5.34        3.2
    5   Nat                         Nan      Nan
    1   2020-09-29 13:23:12         4.5       Nan
    4    NaT                       Nan       Nan
    6    Nat                       Nan       Nan
    2   2020-09-29 13:23:44        Nan       56.4
    3   2020-09-29 13:24:01        24        0.3
```

I've tried multiple approaches including:

```
data_frames = [df,df_2]

df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Date'],
                                                   how='outer'), data_frames)
print(df_merged)
```

and also:

```
 df_f = pd.merge(df, df_2, on='Date', how='outer').fillna(method='ffill')
```

also tried changing the `how` to `inner`, `left`, `right` and so on but did not get the result i want i'd just get combined columns.

**Edit:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-09-29 13:22:57', '2020-09-29 13:23:12', '2020-09-29 13:23:44', '2020-09-29 13:24:01'],
                    'Val1': [5.34, 4.5, np.nan, 24],
                    'Val2': [3.2, np.nan, 56.4, 0.3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-09-29 13:22:57', np.nan,  '2020-09-29 13:23:12', np.nan, np.nan, '2020-09-29 13:23:44', '2020-09-29 13:24:01'],
                    'Val1': [5.34, np.nan, 4.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 24],
                    'Val2': [3.2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 56.4, 0.3]},
                   index=[0,5,1,4,6,2,3])

f_f1 = df1.merge(df2["Date"], on="Date", how="right").set_index(df2.index)
print(f_f1)
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Provide data samples using `df.to_dict()` and `df_2.to_dict()`

Comment: @not_speshal please note that i added the full code with the full dataframes this time and issue reproduced.

Comment: What is the problem here? `print(f_f1)` gives you exactly what you need. Not the previous screenshot you posted.

Comment: no it doesn't, it gave me the exact same value as the previous screenshot, this is so odd lol

Comment: You are clearly sorting the index somehow in your screenshot. When you use `set_index(df2.index)`, you CANNOT get `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` as the index when `df2.index` is `[0,5,1,4,6,2,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
#convert to datetime if needed
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"])

f_f1 = df1.merge(df2["Date"], on="Date", how="right").set_index(df2.index)

>>> df_f
                  Date   Val1  Val2
0  2020-09-29 13:22:57   5.34   3.2
5                  NaN    NaN   NaN
1  2020-09-29 13:23:12   4.50   NaN
4                  NaN    NaN   NaN
6                  NaN    NaN   NaN
2  2020-09-29 13:23:44    NaN  56.4
3  2020-09-29 13:24:01  24.00   0.3
```

###### Inputs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-09-29 13:22:57', '2020-09-29 13:23:12', '2020-09-29 13:23:44', '2020-09-29 13:24:01'],
                    'Val1': [5.34, 4.5, np.nan, 24],
                    'Val2': [3.2, np.nan, 56.4, 0.3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-09-29 13:22:57', np.nan,  '2020-09-29 13:23:12', np.nan, np.nan, '2020-09-29 13:23:44', '2020-09-29 13:24:01'],
                    'Val1': [5.34, np.nan, 4.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 24],
                    'Val2': [3.2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 56.4, 0.3]},
                   index=[0,5,1,4,6,2,3])
```

Comment: hey thank you for you answer, when i applied it, it had a side effect where the index number did change similar to your example, but unlike your example it cause the empty rows to stack up one after the other in the tables which is not what i want.

Comment: Do you want to keep the original index?

Comment: yes with the same row order please.

Comment: @sara - See the edit. I'm not sure what you mean by "it cause the empty rows to stack up one after the other. My answer works as expected on the data sample you provided.

Comment: In my case all the empty lines(in this case rows 5,4 and 6) became right below each other and still are after the edit. And you're right i understand there's no way i could put my entire data though to simulate, i'll try to find a minimum that would reproduce the issue and update the question if that's ok.

Comment: Cannot repoduce. See the input dataframes I use. Identical to your example.

Comment: "i added all the details to your answer". What? Please don't edit my answer. Edit your question if needed.

Comment: I tried with the modified example and my code still works. No idea what you're doing differently.

Comment: Added dataframe code instead of screenshot under Second Edit in my question and was able to reproduce with data frame instead of excel input,

Comment: The issue was with the pandas version i'm using, 1.1.15 upgraded to 1.3.5 and works perfectly now.